# React : Change state of checkbox in term of other checkbox

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using checkbox of material ui, and I want to to change the state of a checkbox when an other checkbox is checked.

```
<Checkbox label="Etape 1 terminée" value={this.state.valueCheckStepOne} onCheck={this.onCheckStepOne} />



<Checkbox label="Etape 2 terminée" value={this.state.valueCheckStepTwo} onCheck={this.onCheckStepTwo} />

onCheckStepOne = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        valueCheckStepOne: value.target.checked

    });      
onCheckStepTwo = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            valueCheckStepTwo: value.target.checked
        }); 

// Here I want to change the state of valueCheckStepOne 
       componentDidUpdate() {        
        if (this.state.valueCheckStepTwo == true) {
            this.setState({
                valueCheckStepOne : true
            })
        }       
    }
```

If i do that, my application bug !
Do you have an idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function **onCheckStepTwo** as

```
onCheckStepTwo = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.checked
    const stateUpdates = {
        valueCheckStepTwo: value
    }
    if (value) {
        stateUpdates.valueCheckStepOne = true
    }
    this.setState(stateUpdates);
}
```

This will change the state of **valueCheckStepOne** if value of **valueCheckStepTwo** is being set as true. You can modify the logic here as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand. I try to do that, but it doesn't work, i can't declare stateUpdates like that, i must declare this like a state ..